# Custom Sections in TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, transient

I have scoured some posts on this site but haven't found my exact issue so I am looking for some advice. I currently have an app with a TaskList entity which I use to back my current TableView. I would like to create sections based on multiple attributes of the entity. For example, I have a "isShared `bool` attribute and a "completed" `bool` attribute and I would like to display sections to group "shared" items, "not shared" items and "completed" items.

Is this a situation where the transient property would work? Most of the applications I have seen only apply to a single attribute, so I haven't been able to wrap my brain around it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea in my head, but this might not be the best solution. Can you create three arrays containing objects for "isShared", "notShared" and "completed" based on your bool attributes?

Then in your tableview cell methods

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //Custom your cell for different section here
    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
         //First section is shared item
         case 0:
              if(cell == nil){
                  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
             //Custom your cell here, for example, you can assign an item in your list to the cell's textlable
             cell.textLabel.text = [sharedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
             }
             break;
         case 1:
              if(cell == nil){
                   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
              //Custom your cell for not shared item here
              cell.textLabel.text = [notSharedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
              }
              break;
          case 2:
              if(cell == nil){
                   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
              //Custom your cell for not shared item here
              cell.textLabel.text = [CompletedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
              }
               break;
          default:
               break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

So you get three sections in table view grouped by the bool attributes. If you change one item in your list, i.e. shared one unshared item from unshared section, then you might need to implement a method to move that object from unSharedArray to sharedArray, then call

```
[tableView reloadData]
```

to refresh the table View.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary with arrays. I would fill the dictionary in the init or the viewDidLoad method of the TableViewController.